# How to replace content of one table with another?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables say Student_Bkp and Student.

I want to replace all the content of Student table with Student_Bkp table.

please let me know how to do it in pl/sql dev to perform above operation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

First you should clean the Student table with a delete sentence and late you can do an insert into:

```
DELETE FROM Student; 

INSERT INTO Student(Columns..)
SELECT columns
FROM Student_Bkp
```

Comment: The best approach is to use `truncate table` rather than `delete`.